# Want to show my index view to non-logged in users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

So I don't apply an authenticate filter to my index action, but non-logged in users are still unable to access the index view because of this line: `:class => "up_arrow #{current_user.votes_for(video).value == 1 ? 'voted' : 'unvoted' }"` which determines whether or not a button should be styled depending on whether the user has voted on the element. However, since `current_user` is not defined for a logged out user, accessing the page brings up an error. I don't want this to happen. How can I fix this so that if `current_user` is nil, the user can still view the page, and the button receives the class `'unvoted'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:class => "up_arrow #{
  current_user && current_user.votes_for(video).value == 1 ? 'voted' : 'unvoted' 
}"
```

Comment: ahh, of course! then again.. i can't test this until I'm successfully able to logout of my app lol: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414596/the-action-destroy-could-not-be-found-for-sessionscontroller-but-its-there

Answer (score 0):

```
class: "up_arrow #{current_user.try(:votes_for, video).try(:value) == 1 ? 'voted' : 'unvoted'}"
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `try` method does please?

Comment: It is a rails method defined on `Object` class. It tries to apply the method (the first argument, expressed as a symbol) if possible and go on. In that case, the other arguments will be passed as the arguments. If the method is not applicable, it returns `nil` and does not return an error. Particularly, if you have `nil`, it simply returns `nil`. See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try

Comment: Forget about the latter half using `zero?`. Sorry.