# Can't find the the 'destroy' action, but it's there... weird error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logout

My app can't seem to find the 'destroy' action in my Sessions controller. Weird, because it's there.

I have a link like so:

```
<%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>
```

Which I route to my destroy action in `routes.rb`:

```
match '/logout' => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
```

And here is the 'destroy' action in my sessions controller:

```
def destroy
  reset_session
  redirect_to videos_path
end
```

When I click the link, I get this error in my logs:

```
Started GET "/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at Thu Mar 24 02:58:36 -0700 2011

AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'destroy' could not be found for SessionsController):
```

What's going on here?

UPDATE:

Here's my routes.rb file:

```
root :to => "videos#new"
resources :videos
resources :video_votes
resources :users
resource :session
match '/login' => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
match '/logout' => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
```

Output of `SessionsController.instance_methods`:

["protected_instance_variables", "asset_path", "hidden_actions?", "with_warnings", "inspect", "content_type", "new_polymorphic_url", "authenticate_with_http_basic", "new_user_path", "details_for_lookup", "allow_forgery_protection=", "view_context", "protected_instance_variables=", "asset_path=", "default_url_options", "authenticate_with_http_token", "**id**", "content_type=", "assign_shortcuts", "_routes", "_save_fragment", "default_url_options=", "hash_for_new_session_path", "redirect_to_facebox", "edit_video_path", "_layout_conditions", "enable_warnings", "new_polymorphic_path", "request_http_basic_authentication", "hash_for_new_user_url", "methods", "append_view_path", "request_http_token_authentication", "hash_for_logout_path", "hidden_actions", "_layout_conditions=", "**send**", "hash_for_edit_video_vote_path", "handler_for_rescue", "expire_action", "new_session_path", "hidden_actions=", "gem", "caching_allowed?", "hash_for_edit_video_url", "asset_host", "_renderers?", "to_json", "singleton_methods", "page_cache_extension", "authenticate", "new_user_url", "nil?", "asset_host=", "responder", "logout_path", "action_methods", "formats", "prepend_view_path", "edit_video_vote_path", "_handle_method_missing", "page_cache_extension=", "_one_time_conditions_valid_16?", "protect_against_forgery?", "rescue_handlers", "responder=", "hash_for_new_session_url", "breakpoint", "formats=", "perform_caching", "require_dependency", "verify_authenticity_token", "edit_video_url", "to_yaml_properties", "form_authenticity_token", "rescue_handlers=", "with_options", "protected_methods", "silence_stderr", "perform_caching=", "equal?", "duplicable?", "hash_for_logout_url", "mimes_for_respond_to", "hash_for_edit_video_vote_url", "_render_option_json", "record_key_for_dom_id", "class_eval", "append_info_to_payload", "new_session_url", "mimes_for_respond_to=", "callback", "responder?", "private_methods", "silence_stream", "hash_for_edit_user_path", "send", "hash_for_root_path", "html_safe?", "performed?", "eql?", "current_user", "to_yaml", "decode_b", "logout_url", "id", "edit_video_vote_url", "_render_option_js", "verified_request?", "sanitize_dom_id", "hash_for_video_path", "_render_template", "handle_unverified_request", "instance_eval", "render", "edit_user_path", "public_methods", "cache_page", "hash_for_root_url", "respond_to", "type", "_render_option_xml", "hash_for_edit_session_path", "action_has_layout?", "hash_for_video_url", "mimes_for_respond_to?", "translate", "instance_exec", "hash_for_edit_user_url", "suppress", "instance_variables", "blank?", "hash_for_videos_path", "method_for_action", "b64encode", "class", "_render_option_update", "url_options", "hash_for_video_vote_path", "singleton_class", "lookup_context", "edit_session_path", "reset_session", "video_url", "unloadable", "instance_variable_get", "encode64", "dispatch", "present?", "edit_user_url", "videos_path", "==", "hash_for_rails_info_properties_path", "presence", "head", "_view_paths?", "===", "clone", "session", "fresh_when", "video_vote_path", "_normalize_options", "config", "find_template", "view_context_class", "response_body", "fragment_cache_key", "hash_for_edit_session_url", "form_authenticity_param", "hash_for_video_votes_path", "view_context_class=", "logged_in?", "debugger", "instance_variable_set", "response_body=", "locale", "authenticate_or_request_with_http_digest", "hash_for_user_path", "=~", "_helper_methods", "access_denied", "hash_for_videos_url", "create", "rails_info_properties_path", "dup", "cache_store", "polymorphic_path", "locale=", "hash_for_video_vote_url", "_helper_methods=", "instrument_fragment_cache", "edit_session_url", "process", "cache_store=", "_renderers", "object_id", "video_votes_path", "_process_action_callbacks", "fragment_exist?", "as_json", "user_path", "respond_to?", "_renderers=", "expires_in", "stale?", "render_to_facebox", "read_fragment", "videos_url", "acts_like?", "allow_concurrency", "hash_for_rails_info_properties_url", "template_exists?", "send_action", "returning", "taint", "expires_now", "video_vote_url", "t", "assets_dir", "view_paths", "_helpers", "allow_concurrency=", "params", "redirect_to", "middleware_stack", "to_enum", "hash_for_video_votes_url", "assets_dir=", "instance_variable_defined?", "require_or_load", "_prefix", "_helpers=", "params=", "authenticate_with_http_digest", "hash_for_user_url", "middleware_stack=", "dom_class", "write_fragment", "new_video", "retrieve_response_from_mimes", "_layout_conditions?", "rails_info_properties_url", "to_param", "hash_for_users_path", "javascripts_dir", "cache", "root_url", "extend", "new", "enum_for", "video_votes_url", "javascripts_dir=", "localize", "request_http_digest_authentication", "user_url", "send_file", "dom_id", "tainted?", "notice", "hash_for_new_video_path", "respond_with", "env", "to_query", "load", "consider_all_requests_local", "untaint", "users_path", "render_to_string", "try", "env=", "headers", "hash_for_login_path", "consider_all_requests_local=", "instance_of?", "view_runtime", "`", "require_association", "headers=", "hash_for_session_path", "send_data", "decode64", "new_video_path", "default_url_options?", "view_runtime=", "_helpers?", "logger", "instance_values", "require", "hash_for_users_url", "freeze", "stylesheets_dir", "rescue_handlers?", "login_path", "logger=", "kind_of?", "status", "hash_for_new_video_vote_path", "stylesheets_dir=", "response", "suppress_warnings", "session_path", "controller_name", "hash_for_new_video_url", "status=", "controller_path", "response=", "action_has_layout=", "instance_variable_names", "collect_mimes_from_class_level", "users_url", "l", "edit_polymorphic_url", "authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic", "request_forgery_protection_token", "render_to_body", "run_callbacks", "hash_for_login_url", "video_path", "is_a?", "new_video_vote_path", "method", "request_forgery_protection_token=", "load_dependency", "db_runtime", "hash_for_session_url", "tap", "frozen?", "new_video_url", "_helper_methods?", "copy_instance_variables_from", "url_for", "alert", "to_a", "page_cache_directory", "db_runtime=", "flash", "login_url", "rescue_action", "page_cache_directory=", "_handle_render_options", "polymorphic_url", "hash_for_new_video_vote_url", "display", "expire_fragment", "taguri", "cleanup_view_runtime", "session_url", "close_facebox", "location", "default_render", "to_s", "silence_warnings", "taguri=", "helpers_path", "request", "edit_polymorphic_path", "hash_for_new_user_path", "action_name", "_view_paths", "location=", "hash", "authenticate_or_request_with_http_token", "initialize_template_class", "helpers_path=", "request=", "new_video_vote_url", "action_name=", "_view_paths=", "rescue_with_handler", "require_library_or_gem", "expire_page", "to_yaml_style", "middleware_stack?", "redirect_from_facebox", "root_path", "allow_forgery_protection", "hash_for_edit_video_path"]

Here's my entire Sessions controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to videos_path
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login/password combination"
      render :action => 'new'
    end

    def destroy
      reset_session
      redirect_to videos_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: have you tried restarting your server? also double check if your destroy action was accidentally put inside private. i've made that mistake a couple of times before

Comment: yeah I have restarted it and the method is not private...

Comment: hmm wierd.... cant see anything wrong

Comment: hehe. Sure. I will see if i can figure it though.

Comment: thanks! let me know if you'd like to see more code.

Comment: Can you post the output of `SessionsController.instance_methods`?

Comment: your login route works fine? show your entire sessions_controller

Comment: Ya, please post your entire controller. `#instance_methods` doesn't include destroy so there has to be something weird with the method definition, `SessionController` is referencing a different controller altogether (in a gem or something), `#undef_method` is being called somewhere, or something absolutely irregular is happening. If you change the method name to `def kill_session` and update the routes does it work?

Comment: just posted my entire sessions controller

Comment: o wow! it was the wrong placement of `end`!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like I messed up the placement of `end` in my Sessions controller that was causing my destroy method to not work...

I had to change my Sessions controller to:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
  if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to videos_path
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login/password combination"
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to videos_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line :

```
match '/logout' => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
```

and make it look like this one :

```
get '/logout' => "sessions#destroy", :as => "logout"
```

it's the same route but it will respond only to get request for this specific action.

Comment: it is actually `delete` method (wich is naturaly `post`) but not `get`

Answer (score -1):

Ok I think I got it

Change routes.rb to

```
resources :sessions
```